# Bibliography not working with Revtex 4.1

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I've drafted a paper and had all the citations working fine, but now I'm trying to incorporate it into the Physical Review Letters template and I can't make the bibliography work. My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[preprint,preprintnumbers,nofootinbib,nobibnotes,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prl,floatfix,]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\cite{Leggett2002}

\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

where there's a file called library.bib in the same folder, contatining

```
@article{Leggett2002,
author = {Leggett, AJ},
file = {:Users/dg813/Dropbox/papers/PhysicaC-2002.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Journal of Physics: Condensed Matter},
pages = {415--451},
title = {{Testing the limits of quantum mechanics: motivation, state of play, prospects}},
url = {http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-8984/14/15/201},
volume = {14},
year = {2002}
}
```

I'm working in Texmaker, and when I compile it just produces a PDF containing `[?]` and no bibliography. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: True, but the RevTex readme says its best not to, as the documentclass already includes the information. I have using \bibliographystyle{} too, with the arguments `ieeetr, plainnat, aipauth4-1` but to no avail

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see. But I get it. 

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl2Wh.png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You need a `\bibliographystyle` statement

Comment: `revtex` takes care of setting the right `bibliographystyle`. The example runs without any error. Why it doesn't work for the OP is unclear, it is probably a matter of not calling `bibtex`. I vote to close as duplicate of the question mark question.